# draw on a picture with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw the movements of soccer players on a soccer pitch.

I already found out how I can [draw on a picture](https://kohske.wordpress.com/2010/12/26/use-image-for-background-in-ggplot2/) using ggplot but I cannot figure out how I can scale the picture.

My movement data is normalized to the range `[0,1]`. Now I want to scale a picture of a soccer pitch so that the lower left-hand corner has the coordinates `(0,0)` and the upper right-hand corner has `(1,1)`.

Comment: have you tried the package `ggimage` ? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggimage/vignettes/ggimage.html

Comment: You could also check out packages `ggsoccer`, `socermatics` (both on GitHub) if you are not set on manually drawing the pitch

Comment: It's obviously `soccermatics`

Comment: use backticks (`) to format inline code in Stack Overflow's markdown editor.